# Netflix conductor : Customer client in Java

Tags: netflix

We are planning to deploy Netflix conductor war in PCF and then create a Conductor client in Java that will communicate with the server and load the json(tasks and workflow creation ) on start up

Can we create the JSONs and load them at client start-uo ? I have tried googling but unable to find sample Conductor Client that can create workflows etc

Any help in pointing to this direction would be helpful.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clients are like listeners with capability of doing the work (workers) and reporting back the status of the task to the conductor. This listening ability comes after a task of specific type is already scheduled by the conductor. For all this to happen the task definitions and workflow definition (metadata) should be fed into the conductor followed by the workflow execution through the rest end-point.

Why do you want to load the workflow tasks and definitions in the startup? Looks like you are using in-memory mode for your POC. For the workflow definitions and tasks to load on startup, use an external dynomite and elasticsearch configured. So that you will not required to load these every time you restart your server.

Hope this helps.